# VS Code Analysis suppress all with same Rule ID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis, suppress-warnings

I am using C# with visual studio. I set up my project so that it runs code analysis on build, but I want to suppress all errors of the same type so I changed lines in the suppression file from this

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1702:CompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly", MessageId = "FieldBus", Scope = "namespace", Target = "JohnsonControls.FieldBusFDD")]
```

to this:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1702:CompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly")]
```

the issue is that it doesn't suppress any warnings then.

1) It what im trying to do possible?

2) if so, how do I go about this?

Comment: You need to open the ruleset in the project properties page, disable the rules you want, save it as a new ruleset and set the project to use it.

Comment: @AlexK. make that an answer and I'll select it